# Google Ads - App download campaign - add in google play store url with UTM parameters

Tags: android, firebase, performance, traffic-measurement, google-ads-api

It was my first time to do app download campaign via google ads. I created a Universal app campaign and has no idea how to add in my tracking parameter on my campaign level. I have tried to append the tracking parameters with final url suffix, however, I've been informed there was no eligible ads found while all my 3 ads are approved.

**- The app store link is :** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yuurewards.app

**- The part I tried to append via final url suffix but failed:** referrer=utm_source%3DSCMP%26utm_medium%3DEM%26utm_content%3DPerformance_EM_IG_v2_app_store%26utm_campaign%3Dapps-launch%26anid%3Dadmob

**- What I expect to have for the final url:** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yuurewards.app&referrer=utm_source%3DSCMP%26utm_medium%3DEM%26utm_content%3DPerformance_EM_IG_v2_app_store%26utm_campaign%3Dapps-launch%26anid%3Dadmob

Would you please let me know how to append the utm parameters for my app download campaign so that my client can differentiate the downloads are coming from my campaign?